# CORS issue with PHP (Yii2) AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, yii2, cors

Keep getting the cors issue.
Have already tried the following:

1. adding code you can see in the image in yii2
2. have installed the Cors Plugin in firefox

API URL : http://thisisbig.ae/advanced/backend/web/customersapi/update/?id=2

[image]

Comment: http://thisisbig.ae/advanced/backend/web/customersapi/update/?id=2 responds to an OPTIONS request with 405 *“Method Not Allowed. This URL can only handle the following request methods: PUT, PATCH”*. It needs to instead respond to OPTIONS requests with a 200 OK. The error message shown in the question indicates that what’s failing is the CORS preflight OPTIONS request sent by the browser automatically on its own.

Comment: @sideshowbarker - ok but i have put 'options' in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'

Comment: Yeah simply putting 'options' in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' value is not sufficient. And to be clear, you’re setting that on the `http://thisisbig.ae/advanced/backend/web/customersapi/update/` server backend, right? That’s your server and you control the config for it?

Comment: @sideshowbarker - yes I do

Comment: have you attached `corsFilter` behavior to your controller ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam - tried many things. Found the solution below.

Answer (score 2):

In the back-end ( Yii2 ), needed to override the verbs() function in the controller and add 'OPTIONS' for the 'update' value

```
protected function verbs()
{
    return [
        'index' => ['GET', 'HEAD'],
        'view' => ['GET', 'HEAD'],
        'create' => ['POST'],
        'update' => ['PUT', 'PATCH','OPTIONS'],
        'delete' => ['DELETE'],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a behavior to define this

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'index'  => ['GET'],
                'view'   => ['GET'],
                'create' => ['GET', 'POST'],
                'update' => ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST'],
                'delete' => ['POST', 'DELETE'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

You can also use CORS filter by attaching it as a behavior to a controller or module, like the following,

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'corsFilter' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
        ],
    ];
}
```

you can also use CORS filter to restrict parameters, like this,

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'corsFilter' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
            'cors' => [
                // restrict access to
                'Origin' => ['http://www.myserver.com', 'https://www.myserver.com'],
                // Allow only POST and PUT methods
                'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['POST', 'PUT'],
                // Allow only headers 'X-Wsse'
                'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['X-Wsse'],
                // Allow credentials (cookies, authorization headers, etc.) to be exposed to the browser
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
                // Allow OPTIONS caching
                'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 3600,
                // Allow the X-Pagination-Current-Page header to be exposed to the browser.
                'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => ['X-Pagination-Current-Page'],
            ],

        ],
    ];
}
```